# Regular Expression in PHP to filter @name or @name.lastname

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter-3, preg-match-all

I have a regular expression like preg_match_all (PHP) that filters emails in text.

**Example**:

```
txt = " tenho ujm texto onde tem um e-mail georgios@teste.com e seu amigos <a> georgios@lask.com </a> 
        mirian@bagato.com sem contar";

return: georgios@teste.com, georgios@lask.com, mirian@bagato.com
```

I need to filter from a text, all @firstname.name or @name.

**Example:**

```
txt = "Testando se essa pescaria é valida @ju1lio.leao, se não for aciona @alycianne.
Importante deixar @mirian ciente. E a @simone.akemi de sobreaviso.";

return: @mirian,@ju1lio.leao,@alycianne,@simone.akemi
```

I'm currently using the patterns:

```
pattern = '/\@([a-z0-9\-])+/i'; 
pattern1 = '/\@(([a-z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-z0-9])+/i';

Return: Array
(
    [0] => @alycianne
    [1] => @ju1lio
    [2] => @ju1lio.leao
    [3] => @mirian
    [4] => @simone
    [5] => @simone.akemi
)
```

The expressions are filtering names from text incorrectly. Some help/idea ?

Comment: `/\@[a-z0-9\-\.]+/`, you forgot to include the `.` in the first pattern

Comment: @CodeSpirit Thank you. Works!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `\@[a-z0-9\-\.]+` for the first pattern will also match the dot in `@alycianne.` which looks like the end of the string.

In the second pattern that you tried `\@(([a-z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-z0-9])+` you are repeating the first group 1 or more times. That group ends on a dot, so to get a match, there should be at least a dot.

The second part of the group is also repeated 1 or more times, so there should also be at least a char a-z0-9 after the dot.

---

To get all 4 matches, you can make the first group optional using `*`

```
@(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)*[a-z0-9]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FmOk4n/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/IS4IS)

**Note** that you don't have to escape the `\@` and that you can repeat the character class itself `[a-z0-9]+` instead of matching a single char in a capture group and then repeat the group.

*Example code*

```
$txt = "Testando se essa pescaria é valida @ju1lio.leao, se não for aciona @alycianne.
Importante deixar @mirian ciente. E a @simone.akemi de sobreaviso.";
$pattern = "/@(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)*[a-z0-9]+/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => @ju1lio.leao
    [1] => @alycianne
    [2] => @mirian
    [3] => @simone.akemi
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one pattern:

```
$pattern = '/\@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.?[a-z0-9-]+)/';
```